# proximity-based fob security device with bluetooth: how it works

Tags: android, ios, bluetooth, proximity, rssi

i have been reading about proximity security devices through bluetooth, but i am wondering how it works in reality. As far as i have been reading, there are two techniques:

1. constant scanning from a master. The central device scans the target device every x minutes. When the target is into range, it gives back MAC bluetooth address and RSSI. The negative side is that being constantly into discoverable mode drains the battery, so does the master device that has to be constantly scanning for devices.
2. Paired and connected. As some product details: "Your laptop locks itself down when you step a certain distance away, and opens again once you're in range". It means that after paring and connected processes, the master can have information when the slave device is out of range, or get inside range again. In bluetooth 4, is going to be even as a profile.

Regarding to the second option, which feature is this? how it works? i mean, maybe you can code a sequence number counter that counts everytime the slave sends a packet through RFCOMM every x milisecs (android or ios), but what i dont understand is how a slave can connect to master again in a transparent way, when normally two bluetooth devices disconnect when they are out of range each other (so you cant send information again from the same bluetooth socket RFCOMM connection).

How proximity devices works in reality? how can you code it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bluetooth 4.0 (BT Low Energy) is a whole other animal than traditional Bluetooth.  It is designed from the ground up to be good at things like the Proximity profile you describe.  Basically a computer and a fob create a connection to periodically communicate at a slow interval, say once every 5 seconds.  When you go out of range the connection drops due to a timeout and the PC knows the fob is gone.  The PC side isn't power constrained, so it can constantly or periodically scan for the fob when connections are dropped.  The fob can advertise its presence using infrequent advertisement packets, which costs only a small amount of power.

Note that there is no RFCOMM in BT LE.  Android and other BT stacks currently lack BT LE support because it is too new.  Only a few devices exist which actually use BT LE, so getting much real info is hard right now.  In a few years this will be much bigger.  The new iPhone 4S and new macbooks have the 4.0 BT chips, so you can expect more usage soon.

Comment: thank you very much for your response. I have read tons of docs about new BT 4.0, but i really didn't know that with this new version, the programming paradigm will change also, in terms of how to code connections like RFCOMM in BT 2.x and 3.x. Now connectiosn are much low power, because radios only turn on when periodically have to transmit. But i have three doubts. First, how a connection between master & slave can continue if radios turn off for low power (tipical for sensors).Second,"infrequent advertisement packets" is a new concept before didnt exist in BT 2.x, right?

Comment: And third, how BT 4.0 (IOS or Android) could manage (as i read on specifications) up to 255 active devices transmitting in low power mode (sensor network)? i mean, lots of active devices (active, not in parked mode) turning on/off radios to periodically transmit small bytes of information to a master device, and at the same time, managing tons of them getting out of range and returning again. Is there a maximum of scanned devices that are transmitting "infrequent advertisement packets"?

Comment: i have found a very good article about all this doubts :-): http://www.rtcwirelessmag.com/?p=150.

Comment: yes, that's a good introductory article.  and yes, advertisement packets are new to 4.0.  The entire protocol for establishing a connection is very different from traditional BT.  With 4.0 it is much less overhead for creating a connection, so dealing with devices that sporadically appear and disappear is less of a problem.    4.0 also allows applications where a device only sends advertisements (which can contain a little user data) and never does a full connection (see broadcaster role in article you posted)

Comment: lets imagine up to 255 devices only advertising with little info (up to 27 octets) in connectionless mode (broadcaster mode on, at a high duty cycle for a very limited period of time). Do you think BT 4.0 is capable of making an device (observer role) to be able to listen up to 255 broadcasts and catch them all, even if there are in/out of range? In BT 2.x, in real situations, and on Android plataform for instance, only lets 'discover' no more than 29 unique mac bt address, because of the limitation of 12 secs max of android inquiry process.TJD, you are a fountain of expertise! :-)

Comment: Large number of devices acting as broadcasters would not be very reliable.  You would eventually get some data from them, but you would miss lots of advertisements and have to allow for very long timeouts before declaring a device gone or out of range.  BT uses frequency hopping, so the master only gets the advertisements when it happens to be listening on the right channel.  Best solution for lots of slaves is to have master connect to them with a slow connection interval.

Comment: ,So as a summary :-),the best option would be up to 255 devices in "broadcast role"(only TX,advertisment,doesnt need RX), and one device as a "central role", so it can configure the connection interval to slow mode (max 4 secs according to official specs). Interesting :-). Anyway, BT4.0 officially advertises no limit on the number of active devices,so i guess they designed it to manage that 'number' using frequency hopping.Now we have to wait for IOS and Android to implement BT 4.0 and it profiles in the near future (years?). Thank you very much for your time and expertise TJD. A pleasure.